# Redis data type and commands to create a shopping cart

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, redis

I've been using `redis` with `laravel` for a while now to do simple things like caching data returned from my `lumen` API but very curious to learn more.

My goal is to implement a shopping cart I already have on `mysql` in `redis` and want some advice as to what redis `data types` and `commands` I can use to achieve this.

At the moment I'm using a `mysql` DB with `laravel` `eloquent` to handle my cart operations.

1. Create a Cart
2. Add Items
3. Remove Items
4. Increase Item Qty
5. Decrease Item Qty

I identify each `cart` by either `user_id` if the customer is signed in, `session_id` if customer not signed in or both.

Long story short this is my current setup

[image: DB SETUP]

The `table` relationships are as below;

1. Cart hasMany CartItems
2. Cart hasMany CartModifierItems
3. CartItems belongsTo Cart
4. CartModifierItems belongsTo Cart
5. CartModifierItems belongsTo CartItems

I'm using `laravel` and `lumen` for my backend and `angularJS` for my frontend.. all actions are sent via `$http`.

I've read through all the `redis` `data types` but still not clear which would be best to replicate the system I have in `mysql`

Any advice/guidance/code snippets appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain your goal in using Redis for your shopping cart ?

Comment: @Lucas Replace my current mysql setup with redis and be able to do the same actions (create cart per customer, add items, remove items, increase item qty, decrease item qty, retrieve cart with items and item children)

Comment: What did you end up doing @moh_abk? Curious how your project ended up.